# How could a human with infinite strength crash a planet into earth

Tags: science-based, planets, astrophysics

A bad guy was kicked off earth and lands on another planet or dwarf planet. He has magical powers that let him have as much physical power as he needs to accomplish his goals. He is also extremely smart and has magic that lets his eyes work like telescopes so he can make very precise calculations about large things like planets. His magic also lets him absorb as much knockback from his own strength as he wants so theres no need to consider how close to lightspeed he will fly backwards if he destroys a planet.

For more context about what hes trying to do, the bad guy doesnt want to destroy the earth, he just wants to return. There is someone still on earth who is keeping track of the bad guy (also has magic telescope eyes) and has enough power to shoot a beam of energy that diverts their course if they try to jump to earth directly. If the bad guy jumps with enough force and speed that the defender cant redirect, it would have enough power that he would go right through the earth and destroy it. Instead, the bad guy wants to distract the defender by sending something so difficult to intercept that the defender has to sacrifice their life to save the earth from it, letting the bad guy get back easily.

Now for the actual question, obviously a planet cant get there in one piece, but is there a way for the bad guy to destroy a planet in a way that the majority of its pieces would end up in an elliptical orbit that would collide with the earth years in the future? It can take any amount of years it needs to but id prefer if it takes less than 300. It can be any planet that isnt a gas giant or Venus because he needs to be able to see space to make the calculations. Any ideas would be good but my own idea was just punching it, if that happened would any planet be able to be punched into a specific orbit or would anything subject to that much force just burst everywhere at once so very little of it would go anywhere that was planned.

I also made another post similar to this but it was too specific in that I only got answers that explained how much force would be required to punch mars a specific way and not answers for how to cause any planet to collide with earth. I would appreciate any other ideas for how one person could move a planet as well.

Comment: by spending millions of years hucking rocks in the opposite direction. the problem is the bigger the rock the less speed you can impart before it simply shatters.

Comment: Should we assume that he can also move at super speeds?  Super strength without super speed would not make anything you are saying possible.

Comment: Does the planet have to remain in one piece? Because that's a lot of force to impart on a planet all in one go.

Comment: This question is like asking if you can punch a water balloon across a football field with a toothpick.

Comment: Also, the word "infinite" is always dangerous.  Infinite anything breaks practically any question.

Comment: Reasonable questions: does your planet-pusher need to breathe, eat, or sleep, and are they functionally immortal?  If they have a normal human lifespan but are impossibly strong, the answer is almost certainly no.

Comment: infinite power, magic reaction absorption, magic eyes, magic course diverting energy, and a science-based tag.....good luck!

Comment: @jdunlop how does "infinite" break this question? and in response to your second comment, if he was anything less than immortal he would have died just being in space.

Comment: @Allan the underlying problem is still based on physics. the magic is so people dont focus on problems like where is the power coming from, how fast he would be flying backwards, and how he could have the precision to move planets to a specific area in the first place. as much as I appreciate the effort, long math responses detailing exactly how impossible my idea is doesnt help me any more than just saying "no that wouldnt work"

Comment: It looks like your world is already built and you're asking how events in this world will act.

Comment: @sociocat "infinite strength" basically means you can accellerate _any_ mass towards light speed instantly. you break physics with this.

Comment: @sphennings yeah, I already have ideas that I like, I just want to know if it would work like how I wanted it to or if it's impossible. Am I not allowed to use this site for that purpose?

Comment: @Franz what does breaking physics mean?

Answer (score 2):

## Step one, pick up a big rock on the side that the planet is traveling.

The more mass the better. This rock will be the jet that moves you.

## Step two, throw the rock hard enough that you're knocked through the planet, but not to escape velocity.

This will slow down the orbit of the planet to a notable degree, making the orbit curve inwards towards the sun. You will be pushed through the planet, but don't throw it so hard you're knocked into space.

## Step three, return to the start and repeat.

As long as you can keep throwing things at near light speed, you'll get there eventually.

Comment: I wonder if throwing the rock on the planet-Sun direction (or having a velocity component so oriented) won't be more energy efficient - like in "elongate the orbit of the projectile planet and make it eventually intersect Earth's (after countless of years)".

Comment: The original question was based off mars hitting earth, so I based it off that.

Comment: Yeah, nah, mate. My comment wasn't a critique of your method - just wondering if there are more energy efficient ways than "stopping Mars on its tracks until it falls on Earth" (something like just putting it on a collision course and let gravity take over). But... if you want a critique of the method, you haven't cover the scenario in which Mars ends on the same orbit as Earth, just in a [counter-Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-Earth) position ;)

Comment: thats very creative and helpful! However I have one problem, wouldnt doing that even once put enough force through the planet that it causes a lot more damage than just a human sized hole, or would the planet still stay intact.

Comment: I recommend playing around in Kerbal Space Simulator, Adrian. The most efficient way to aim at a planet is by using retrograde thrust. Throwing the rock sideways is less efficient. 

Gravity would keep most of the plane together, although you would cause huge and devastating earthquakes. That's just the nature of moving a planet. You need to put a lot of energy into it.